# Sorting method in scala

Tags: java, scala, sorting

I want to extend a sort method for scala Array which can return the original indecies.

The code I writed below:

```
object ArrayExtend {
implicit class ArrayExtension(val array: Array[Int]) {
    def argSort(): Array[Int] = {
                var tupleArray = for (i <- 0 until array.length) yield (i, array(i))     

                    tupleArray = tupleArray.sortWith((x,y)=> x._2 < y._2)

                    val result = for((index,_) <- tupleArray) yield index

                    return result.toArray

    }
}


def main(args:Array[String]){
val array = Array(5,4,3,2,0)
for(i <- array.argSort()) print(i)
}
```

}

This code works on Array[Int], how can I extend this method to all different types of Array? I didn't find any compare method in the AnyRef class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's enough if you require that type `T` can be implicitly converter into `Ordered[T]`. Normally it would be done by adding implicit converter to the class or method parameters with `(implicit converter: T => Ordered[T])`, however scala provides **view bounds `<%`** exactly for such cases. From the book: *You can think of "`T <% Ordered[T]`" as saying. " I can use any `T`, as long as `T` can be treated as an `Ordered[T]`."*

So the code would look like this:

```
implicit class ArrayExtension[T <% Ordered[T]](val array: Array[T]) {
  def argSort = array.zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2).toArray
}

val array = Array(5,4,3,2,0)
val array2 = Array(5f,4f,3f,2f,0f)

array.argSort foreach print //43210
println
array2.argSort foreach print //43210
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using an implicit conversion to [`Ordered`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.math.Ordered). You also need to parametrize your type. Change the code to the following:

```
implicit class ArrayExtension[T](val array: Array[T])(implicit view: (T) => Ordered[T]) {
  def argSort(): Array[Int] = {
    var tupleArray = for (i <- 0 until array.length) yield (i, array(i))
    tupleArray = tupleArray.sortWith((x, y) => x._2 < y._2)
    val result = for ((index, _) <- tupleArray) yield index
    result.toArray
 }
```

}

`Ordered` is

> A trait for data that have a single, natural ordering.

and

> Classes that implement this trait can be sorted with scala.util.Sorting and can be compared with standard comparison operators (e.g. > and <).

So any class that implements `Ordered` trait (directly or via an implicit conversion) can be used with sorting methods. You can implement this trait for your own data types in order to make them sortable.